# How to register rb as a template handler in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well since I am using a lot of helper methods in my view files and I avoid using html in most of my view files.

Example

> myview.html.erb

```
<%=myhelper @myobject%>
```

so I end up using,the erb processing tags each time for each file.

```
<%=%>
```

I want to register .rb as a template handler or any other extention for that matter.
So my templates look like

> myview.html.rb

```
myhelper @myobject
```

I am clueless on how to go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it,it seems railscasts already covered that part.

Its show notes,worth checking out.

https://github.com/railscasts/379-template-handlers/blob/master/store-after/config/initializers/ruby_template_handler.rb

Things without ruby are easy to read and render without those erb tags.